# If I enter negative number I should get the output by ignoring negative answer?

Tags: c, algorithm

If user enters a negative number, you can just ignore its sign and consider its corresponding positive value. If user enters zero, then the program should terminate.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long input;
    long reverse = 0;
    long temp;
    printf("Enter the input number: ");
    scanf("%ld", &input); //Read input from user
    temp = input;         //Save input to another variable
    while (temp > 0) {
        // extract last digit from temp and add it as last digit in reverse
        // by moving existing digits one position towards left
        reverse = reverse * 10 + (temp % 10);
        temp = temp / 10; // removes last digit and move other digits to right
    }
    if (input == reverse) // check if input and reverse are same
        printf("Number is a palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("Number is not palindrome\n");
    return 0;
}
```

outputs are like this

```
Enter an integer number: 12321
12321 is a Palindrome.
Enter an integer number: 2312
2312 is not a Palindrome.
Enter an integer number: -45566554
45566554 is a Palindrome.
Enter an integer number: t
Enter an integer number: 36298100189263
36298100189263 is a Palindrome.
Enter an integer number: 362981089263
362981089263 is not a Palindrome.
Enter an integer number: 0
Goodbye!
```

Comment: Simply assign  `input = abs(input)`

Comment: Presumably this is a school assignment or something similar. In that case, what you should do with a negative number depends on what the assignment is. Certainly the string “-121” is not a palindrome, since it is not the same as its reverse, “121-”. However, if the assignment says to ignore the sign, then you should ignore the sign. The definition of a bug is a deviation of a program from its specification. So to know what your program should do, we need to know what its specification is.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the sign of a number, move it to another number and force the sign to be positive:

```
temp = (input < 0) ? -input : input;
```

That's the concise ternary version but you can revert to the more classical if you desire:

```
if (input < 0) {
    temp = -input;
} else {
    temp = input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the number is negative and take its opposite. There is just one special case, `LONG_MIN`, that may not have a positive counterpart. Using unsigned arithmetic takes care of this special case gracefully:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long input;
    unsigned long uinput;
    unsigned long reverse = 0;
    unsigned long temp;
    printf("Enter the input number: ");
    if (scanf("%ld", &input) != 1) // Read input from user
        return 1;
    if (input >= 0) {
        uinput = input;
    } else {
        uinput = -(unsigned long)input;
    }
    temp = uinput;
    while (temp > 0) {
        // extract last digit from temp and add it as last digit in reverse
        // by moving existing digits one position towards left
        reverse = reverse * 10 + temp % 10;
        temp = temp / 10; // removes last digit and move other digits to right
    }
    if (uinput == reverse) // check if input and reverse are same
        printf("Number is a palindrome\n");
    else
        printf("Number is not palindrome\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the `LONG_MIN` case, `-input` overflows before it is assigned to `uinput`. And of course `scanf("%ld",…)` may overflow before this, for input values not representable in `long`.